# CSV file opening in browser even after setting Apache Header

Tags: apache, csv, header, mime-types

I have a csv file in my server for which I show the link and the user is allowed to download it. But the file is being opened directly in IE9 instead of just showing the link. For other browsers its working correctly. I have also done the following setup in my httpd.conf file for Apache.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:csv)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition "attachment"
</FilesMatch>
```

This is working correctly in my local machine, the issue is only happening when I run it in a server.

Comment: Have you checked if your server is actually sending these headers as expected …?

Comment: I am not sure from where can I check this?

Comment: Developers tools in IE ([F12]) do have a network tab that you can use to record HTTP requests & responses.

Comment: I checked the headers are not sent along with the response. One thing to mention here that I am also using Jboss in my server. Now I think the reports are served directly from the Jboss and not via Apache. So is it possible to add the headers from Jboss. I am using Jboss 4.2.3.